# Degenerate Symmetric Bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra

Let f be non-zero symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Suppose there exist linear transformation$ T_i:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},  i=1,2 $ such that for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^3:f(a,b)=T_1(a)T_2(b)$ .
Then:

1.$\ rank\ f=1$
2.$\ \dim \{b\in \mathbb{R}^3| \forall{a \in \mathbb{R}^3}: f(a,b)=0 \}$
3.$\ f$ is a positive semi-definite or  negative semi-definite.
4.$\ \{a\in \mathbb{R}^3:f(a,a)=0 \}$ is a linear subspace of dimension 2.

rank f is 1 by observing matrix of the transformation but I don't know how to calculate dimension of $\{b\in \mathbb{R}^3|\forall{a \in \mathbb{R}^3}:f(a,b)=0\}$. And what about last option. I guess third option is correct. As matrix of f has rank 1. Is my logic is correct? Please guide me.

Comment: $f(a,b)=0 \iff (T_1(a)=0\lor T_2(b)=0)$, and $T_i$ has to be nonzero, in order to $f$ could be nonzero. So there is some $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T_1(a)\neq 0$ and thus $\{b\in \mathbb{R}^3| \forall{a \in \mathbb{R}^3}: f(a,b)=0 \}=\{b\in \mathbb{R}^3: T_2(b)=0 \}=\ker T_2$. Now by [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem): $\dim\ker T_2=\dim\mathbb{R}-\dim \mathcal{Jm}T_2=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminaries:**

I treat the case $T_1=T_2=T$. You will have no difficulty to apply it to the general case.

Linear form $T$ has a $1 \times 3$ matrix, $(u,v,w)$.

Let us denote by $V$ the column vector $V=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}$.

We then have:

$$T_1(A)=V^TA.$$

Thus

$$T_1(A)T_1(B)=(A^TV)(V^TB)=A(VV^T)B$$

Therefore the quadratic form has this matrix:

$$Q=VV^T=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}u&v&w\end{pmatrix}=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}u^2 & uv & uw\\
                         uv & v^2 & vw\\
                         uw & vw & w^2\end{array}\right) $$

**Question 1:** $Q$ is a rank one matrix because its image space (column space) is directed by the unique vector $V$ (first column is $uV$, second column is $vV$, third column is $wV$).

**Question 2:** if you write the equations, you will find a 2 dimensional solution.

**Question 3:** $$X^TQX=X^TVV^TX=(V^TX)^T(V^TX)=\|V^TX\|^2 \geq 0$$

with the possibility that the result is zero when $X$ is orthogonal to $V$.

**Question 4:** Write down the equations resulting from constraint $f(A,A)=0$, i.e., $A^TQA=0$, i.e.,

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}u&v&w\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=0 \iff$$

$$(au+bv+cw)^2=0 \ \iff \ au+bv+cw=0,$$

clearly a dimension 2 subspace called the isotropic space associated with the quadratic form $Q$.

Comment: For option 4, can we say that if quadratic form $q(a)=f(a,a)=0$ hence $a\in kernel(q)$ but dimension of q is 1 hence dim(kernel(q))=2.Is it correct?